# How does the read function work when using a loop?

Tags: python, loops, io, iteration

Let us say we have a file object/stream and we would like to read from that.
That could result into something like this

```
with open("test.txt","r")as i:
        x = i.read()
```

Now if I was to use a loop like:

```
for z in x:
```

What would the iteration be like? Would I iterate over the characters of the text file? And what if the text file contains new lines? For example if my text file was to contain several names and each one written in a new line. For example let us say one name would be "Marcel". What would the iteration be like? Would I iterate over every single letter separately? And what about the "\n" at the end of "Marcel", that would usually indicate a new line? Would I iterate over "backslash" and then over "n" or over both at once?

Comment: since `read()` reads the whole file, iterating will be over each character.

Comment: `file.read()` will read the entire function in one line, and return a string containing its contents. `file.readline()` will read one file at a time. You can also iterate over the file object itself (`i` in this case) to get one line at a time. In your example, with `x = i.read()`, you'd be iterating over the file character-by-character - newlines included!

Comment: Why do you ask what this code *would* do? Why don't you just run it?

Comment: Just test it. Why are you asking something that you could just _do_?

Comment: I did it before asking the question, however I would like to understand a bit more of the theory as I try to apply the knowledge to another code that I do not fully understand.

Comment: I'm afraid that's not really a meaningfully answerable question. I mean, yes, we can objectively tell you what you have already seen when executing the code. Other than that, how much theory? Do you care about how the VM executes bytecode, what the various methods do, about the text handling, how the OS handles files and I/O, or about the block device?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 2):

From the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects):

> To read a file’s contents, call f.read(size), which reads some quantity of data and returns it as a string ... the entire contents of the file will be read and returned; it’s your problem if the file is twice as large as your machine’s memory.

Because it is a string, iterating over the string returns its characters.